# PGSQL counting elements in two different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have problem with SQL statements that will counts elements between two tables that are in many to many relationship:

```
Clients:     | client_id | client_name |
Events:      | client_id | event_id |
```

As a result I need something like this:

```
| client_id | events_counts |
```

Where events_counts will be a number of whole events that are connected to client with client_id

I'm new to SQL and I don't have any idea how I can write this query, I consider to add new column in `Clients` table that will contains this counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an aggregation using GROUP BY and COUNT(*)

```
SELECT client_id, COUNT(*)
FROM events
GROUP BY client_id
```

If you need to display a client name also, then a join must be used:

```
SELECT c.client_id, c.client_name, count(*)
FROM events e
JOIN clients c ON e.client_id = c.client_id
GROUP BY c.client_id, c.client_name
```